# Making a scheduling program to handle recurrent appointments for multiple rooms

Tags: python, html, scheduling

I am new to programming and I am trying to make a appointment scheduling program to handle recurrent appointments.

Let me try to make it simple.

I have 7 rooms - 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 
There are 22 doctors
There are 8 modalities of treatment: A, B, C, D, E, F, G

Each doc has to schedule their patients to one of the rooms for treatment (they need to have log in ID)
Doc will need to enter- 1. the patient name, 2. Hospital ID, 3. Modality of treatment for the patient, 4. No of treatments required

The planned date for start of treatment for each patient will be given by each doc.

Each room can handle about 50 patients a day 
Each patient will require daily treatments in the same room initially allotted for a period of 6-7 weeks (excluding saturdays and sundays).

Once a doc gives the details above and the proposed start of treatment date, the program should be able to give back the nearest possible date and also book the patient for the required no. of slots for the next 6-7 weeks.

I would be grateful if anyone could help me out in this. As told I am new to programming and know a bit about Python and html. So I will need guidance from the core basics as to how to go about.

Comment: This is very broad. Do you have a concrete question that involves actual code? If you are new to programming, you should probably start with smaller problems.

Comment: There are programs already out there that accomplishes this. It will be more beneficial for both you and the clinic to use an already existing one.